# Add a node with same rotation as the vertical plane

Tags: ios, arkit

What i want is to add a node with same rotation as the vertical plane. I have tried by getting the Euler angles of the plane node and assigning it to my 3d object's root node but the result is not as desired see the screenshot. Vertical plane is represented by orange colour.

By adding a simple node without modifying Euler angles. Please note that the the position and Euler angles in dae's root node is 0, 0, 0 while the scale is 1, 1, 1.

```
var scene = SCNScene(named: selectedObject.daeURL)!
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(scene.rootNode)
```

[image]

By assigning Euler angles of the plane node to to my 3d object's root node:

```
var scene = SCNScene(named: selectedObject.daeURL)!
scene.rootNode.eulerAngles = anchorNode.eulerAngles
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(scene.rootNode)
```

[image]

Actual desired result should be:

[image]

Comment: make it child of detected planeAnchor node

Comment: yeah i did the same

Comment: how did you do it? ARPlaneAnchor can't have a child node. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @Anushk see here. [ARKit 1.5 how to get the rotation of a vertical plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011619/arkit-1-5-how-to-get-the-rotation-of-a-vertical-plane)