# Align 3D object parallel to vertical plane detected by estametedVerticalPlane

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have this book, but I'm currently remixing the furniture app from the video tutorial that was free on AR/VR week.

I would like to have a 3D wall canvas aligned with the wall/vertical plane detected.

This is proving to be harder than I thought. Positioning isn't an issue. Much like the furniture placement app you can just get the column3 of the hittest.worldtransform and provide the new geometry this vector3 for position.

But I do not know what I have to do to get my 3D object rotated to face forward on the aligned detected plane.  As I have a canvas object, the photo is on one side of the canvas. On placement, the photo is ALWAYS facing away.

I thought about applying a arbitrary rotation to the canvas to face forward but that then was only correct if I was looking north and place a canvas on a wall to my right.

I'v tried quite a few solutions on line all but one always use .existingPlaneUsingExtent. for vertical plane detections. This allows for you to get the ARPlaneAnchor from the 
`hittest.anchor? as ARPlaneAnchor`. 
If you try this when using `.estimatedVerticalPlane` the `anchor`? is `nil`

I also didn't continue down this route as my horizontal 3D objects started getting placed in the air. This maybe down to a control flow logic but I am ignoring it until the vertical canvas placement is working.

My current train of thought is to get the front vector of the canvas and rotate it towards the front facing vector of the vertical plane detected `UIImage` or the hittest point.

How would I get a forward vector from a 3D point. OR get the front vector from the grid image, that is a `UIImage` that is placed as an overlay when `ARKit` detects a vertical wall?

Here is an example. The canvas is showing the back of the canvas and is not parallel with the detected vertical plane that is the column. But there is a "Place Poster Here" grid which is what I want the canvas to align with and I'm able to see the photo.

[image: canvasback]

Things I have tried.
using `.estimatedVerticalPlane`
[ARKit estimatedVerticalPlane hit test get plane rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029318/arkit-estimatedverticalplane-hit-test-get-plane-rotation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I don't know how to correctly apply this matrix and eular angle results from the SO answer.

my add picture function.

```
func addPicture(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult) {
    // I would like to convert estimate hitTest to a anchorpoint
    // it is easier to rotate a node to a anchorpoint over calculating eularAngles
    // we have all detected anchors in the _Renderer SCNNode. however there are

    // Get the current furniture item, correct its position if necessary,
    // and add it to the scene.
    let picture = pictureSettings.currentPicturePiece()

    //look for the vertical node geometry in verticalAnchors
    if let hitPlaneAnchor = hitTestResult.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
      if let anchoredNode = verticalAnchors[hitPlaneAnchor]{
        //code removed as a .estimatedVerticalPlane hittestResult doesn't get here
      }
    }else{
      // Transform hitresult to world coords
      let worldTransform = hitTestResult.worldTransform
      let anchoredNodeOrientation = worldTransform.eulerAngles
        picture.rotation.y =
          -.pi * anchoredNodeOrientation.y
        //set the transform matirs
        let positionMatris = worldTransform.columns.3
        let position = SCNVector3 (
          positionMatris.x,
          positionMatris.y,
          positionMatris.z
        )
        picture.position = position + pictureSettings.currentPictureOffset();

    }
    //parented to rootNode of the scene
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(picture)
  }
```

Thanks for any help available.

Edited:
I have notice the 'handness' or the 3D model isn't correct/ is opposite?
Positive Z is pointing to the Left and Positive X is facing the camera for what I would expects is the front of the model. Is this a issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid adding node directly into the scene using world coordinates. Rather you should notify the `ARSession` of an area of interest by adding an `ARAnchor` then use the session callback to vend an `SCNNode` for the added anchor.

For example your hit test might look something like:

```
@objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: sender.view)
    guard let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: [.existingPlaneUsingGeometry, .estimatedVerticalPlane]).first,
          let planeAnchor = hitTestResult.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor,
          planeAnchor.alignment == .vertical else { return }
    let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

Here a tap gesture recognized is used to detect taps within an `ARSCNView`. When a tap is detected a hit test is performed looking for existing and estimated planes. If the plane is vertical, we add an `ARAnchor` is added with the `worldTransform` of the hit test result, and we add that anchor to the `ARSession`. This will register that point as an area of interest for the `ARSession`, so we'll receive better tracking and less drift after our content is added there.

Next, we need to vend our `SCNNode` for the newly added `ARAnchor`. For example

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
        let anchorNode = SCNNode()
        anchorNode.name = "anchor"
        return anchorNode
    } else {
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.67, height: 1.0)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "monaLisa")
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(CGFloat.pi * -0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
        let node = SCNNode()
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        return node
    }
}
```

Here we're first checking if the anchor is an `ARPlaneAnchor`. If it is, we vend an empty node for debugging purposes. If it is not, then it is an anchor that was added as the result of a hit test. So we create a geometry and node for the most recent tap. Because it is a vertical plane and our content is lying flat need to rotate it about the x axis. So we adjust it's `eulerAngles` to have it be upright. If we were to return `planeNode` directly adjustment to `eulerAngles` would be removed so we add it as a child node of an empty node and return it.

Should result in something like the following.

[image: Screencast]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. ok I will try adding to session node and report my finds. The next thing to run by you, does your placement logic work with 3D objects grabbed from a .scn file? In your example you're creating a basic scn plane. I'v notice my 3D object X and Z are switched from the estimated plane X and Z. i.e The Z of the plane is facing toward the camera and X goes to the right. on the 3d object X is towards the camera and Z(pos) is to the left.

Comment: To add node on hitTestResult anchor is working fine but I want to add scene (.scn)file on the detected vertical plane. First I am detecting vertical plane and add vertical plane and after hitting on detected vertical plane I want to add that .scn file. That 3D object is not parallel to detected plane. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @mushcraft Perhaps you can post the model you're using. But if you follow the steps above it should now only be a matter of adjusting your model within its local coordinate space, which I would regard as being much easer to reason about.

Comment: @Bhakti Have you posted a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @beyowulf now I have posted question. Please check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286246/how-to-place-3d-object-scn-file-on-detected-vertical-plane-which-should-be-pa

Comment: I am finally coming back to this after another side project, however I already have a similar version to your sample code. The key difference is I don't use ```.existingPlaneUsingGeometry``` only .estimatedVerticalPlane. I think that is what is really causing my issue.

Comment: @beyowulf I am also using renderer(_:didAdd:for:) instead. I don't fully understand the difference in renderer(_:didAdd:for:) and renderer(_:nodefor:), till debugging but in my renderer(_:didAdd:for:) I return if the givenobject isn't a ARPlaneAnchor. If it is I draw a "place image here" Plane.  I then want user to tap that place image plane to place the new object. These new nodes aren't being added to the session node but separately. So I am trying to implement your suggestion to added it to the session Node. Which I am actively trying to figure out now.